# Getting error when trying to pass a parameter with apex:param

Tags: apex-param, outputlink

When I click on a tab I also want to update the pageNumber custom string on my controller, but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tab3?1=3
>              jquery.min.js:2

```
<apex:form id="formId">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
            <apex:outputLink value="#tab3" html-data-toggle="tab">tab 3
                <apex:param name="1" value="3" assignTo="{!pageNumber}" />
            </apex:outputLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</apex:form>


Custom Field:
public Integer pageNumber {get; set;}
```

Comment: Bit unusual way of doing it though. You can try doing the same thing with a command link rather than using JS . eg. `<apex:commandLink action="{!incrementPageNo}" value="#tab3" />` ? then in controller you have a method to increment the page number.

Comment: If you want to use the outputLink, you need to combine it with an actionFunction. Otherwise, you can use a commandLink and call your code in an onComplete handler.

Comment: The problem with commandLink is that it throws an error because I use bootstrap tabs, outputLink does not.

Comment: Also commandLink refreshes the page if I don't specify reRender value and I don't want/can't use this attribute

Comment: can you @sfdcfox show an example of using it with actionFunction?

Comment: @Dante You still need to use a reRender attribute, or nothing you attempt to do will work. This is because without a reRender attribute, both commandLink and actionFunction will end up reloading the whole page, which I presume is not your intent.